# How do Events work in the Sonos Cloud API?

Tags: sonos

Various parts of the Sonos Cloud API include subscribe/unsubscribe calls, but I don't see any example of how those events get delivered to the caller. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for how to subscribe to and handle events can be found [here](https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/connect/).

Comment: Ahah, THAT is what I was missing. Thanks.